# Alpha not working properly in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I'm trying to make this transparent lightning but some of the bits Just won't be transparent. but the thing is its only happening on cycles, on Eevee/material mode its completely normal[image]

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your shader network where you are using the Alpha channels at all.  You're using the color channels of your images but leaving the Alpha behind?  Eevee might display the textures with their alpha, but with Cycles you need to use that alpha channel explicitly.

Comment: It also seems as if you used the Add Shader, which I don't think keeps the alpha channel intact. I'd use a Mix Shader node with the alpha channel as the factor.